# Create a UIView from NIB

Tags: ios, uiview, nib

I have created a custom class that subclasses UIView. I want to do my layout in IB, so have set outlets. The problem is how do I initialise my view so that I get it from the NIB? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UIView *info = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWeather" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Where do I put this? I've put it in my View's class init method and am then adding this view as a subview but still no luck.

Comment: I put it in my UIViewController `init` and call `[self.view addSubview]` too. All looks good.

Comment: Very nice solution. But it only works when the UIView is not to be updated.